# closure in javascript using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, closures

I am trying to make a closure that does the following:

> Input: The argument f can be assumed to be a function which takes a single argument which is an integer and returns a single integer.
>
> Output: makeClosure should return an array of exactly two functions which we will call f1 and f2.  These two functions should be contained in a closure which also defines a shared variable named 'max' (i.e. 'max' is accessible to both).  'max' should be initialized to 0 by makeClosure.  f1 should be a function which takes a single integer argument and, if and only if its value is greater than max, sets max equal to that value.  f1 should take no arguments and return the result of calling f with max as its argument.

This is the code I have tried which doesn't work.

```
function makeClosure(f) {
    function getMax(f1, f2) {
        var getMax = [];
        f.forEach(function(f1,f2) {
            getMax.push(Math.max.apply(null, f));
        });
    return getMax;
    }
```

Comment: "*makeClosure should return an array of exactly two functions*"…

Comment: Are you aware that the function you wrote doesn't return anything?

Comment: Actually, the function you wrote doesn't do *any* of the things required by the description.

Comment: This is my first experience using closures and I am kind of lost. I have read about them quite a bit but cannot seem to make one that works.

Comment: Keep calm. Forget about closures first. Start by doing what your exercise asks you, without the closure requirement. Closure will be simple after that.

Comment: Can someone give me an example of a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function makeClosure(f) {
    var max = 0;
    return [
        function f1(v) {
            max = Math.max(max, v);
        }, function f2() {
            return f(max);
        }
    ];
}
```